# How to fix Avoid unused parameters PHPMD of protected method in parent class

Tags: symfony, phpmd

I have two class :

```
class EntityVoter
{
    protected function canPutToBlockChain($entity, $viewer)
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

```
class VerificationVoter extends EntityVoter
{
    public function canPutToBlockChain($entity, $viewer)
    {
        return $this->canShare($entity, $viewer);
    }
}
```

PHPMD scan EntityVoter class and throw: Avoid unused parameters such as '$entity', '$viewer'.

My solution is creating a interface:

```
interface EntityVoterInterface 
{
     function canPutToBlockChain($entity, $viewer);
}
```

and then add `@inhericDoc` annotation:

```
class EntityVoter implements EntityVoterInterface
{
    /**
     * @inheritDoc
     */
    protected function canPutToBlockChain($entity, $viewer)
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Is there any better solution ?

Comment: Just pure curiosity, what are those voter class ? are you not using `use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authorization\Voter\VoterInterface;`

Comment: @DylanKas Yes, I have extended abstract class `Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authorization\Voter` on `EntityVoter` class already. I just would like to focus on phpmd scanning.

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to suppress PHPMD warning for the rule on the method:

```php
class EntityVoter
{
    /**
     * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.UnusedFormalParameter)
     */
    protected function canPutToBlockChain($entity, $viewer)
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

For more information, see [PHPMD Suppressing Warnings @ PHP Mess Detector documentation](https://phpmd.org/documentation/suppress-warnings.html).

I would not use wildcard exclusion such as `@SuppressWarnings("unused")` but targeted exclusion is OK for warnings linked to third-party code.